# AWS No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Nice to meet you!
There is anyone who has handled the problem that related to Inode in the EC2. My EC2 goes on increasing the memory, that cause "No space left on device" errors.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/

I have resolved this as the above link. But i don't know wherether is there another way to solve this issue. Because , i don't want to keep going to increase my EBS memory when it got full.
Looking forward to your help!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly store your data **outside of an instance** in storage systems such as S3 or [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). In both cases there are no limits on the amount of data you can store, thus you wouldn't need to worry about it.

Also your data would be available across **multiple availability zones** (AZs). Which is in contrast to EBS storage, which is limited to only one AZ.

Nevertheless, the use of S3 or EFS would require changes to your applications or instance setup. EFS probably would be easier to adopt in this respect.